mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - Address already in use
I am trying a mount a share it fails with following error.
[support@cohesity-005056bd7880-node-1 ~]$ sudo mount -vvv -o nfsvers=3,soft,intr,noatime,retrans=10,timeo=600,retry=0,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,sync,tcp 10.2.193.121:/suresh_test1 ~/suresh_test1
mount.nfs: timeout set for Wed Oct  2 22:14:40 2024
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,soft,intr,retrans=10,timeo=600,retry=0,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,tcp,nolock,addr=10.2.193.121'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - Address already in use
mount.nfs: Address already in use

Error seen for any ipaddress. So this is not a nfs server issue. It looks like the we are running out of the source port. How to find the reason behind this failure?

Probably this is related to the local lockd process that is needed for nfsv3 clients
